# Yesod static file server bug?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I use Yesod (ver. 1.1.9.2), and I am testing my web app using `yesod devel` and/or `cabal build && cabal install && MyWebApp Production` in my local Mac OSX (10.8.2) environment.

I sometimes have 404 errors for static files I keep in `/static` subfolders. While testing my app, I keep modifying my static files under those folders and see the result, but at some point, the server starts to respond with 404 errors for static files (not only the files I modified, but any other files in those folders). I suspect this is a bug of Yesod, and I am thinking to report an issue on their github repo, but does anyone have any information about this kind of problem?

My `yesod-static` is ver. 1.1.2.2.